# Load data from text file to mysql server in android

Tags: php, android, mysql

i have the following code that am using to load text file with data to mysql table:

```
private final String filepath = "/mnt/sdcard/acc.txt";
private String acc;
public void insert()
{
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(filepath,acc));


    try
    {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://testandroid.net/insert.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
}
    catch(Exception e)
{
        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}     

    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
}
    catch(Exception e)
{
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
}     

try
{
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
        code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

        if(code==1)
        {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
        Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
}
}
```

and this is my phpfile on the server

```
<?php
    $host='xxx';
    $uname='yyy';
    $pwd='cfd';
    $db="dxw";

    $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

    $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];

    $flag['code']=0;

    if($r=mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE '$filepath' INTO TABLE xfr) ",$con))
{

        $flag['code']=1;
        echo"hi";
    }

    print(json_encode($flag));
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I keep getting invalid ip address error. I don't know what am doing wrong. Please help. I want to load the textfile in mysql server

Comment: You catch an exception and then you toast an "Invalid IP Address" instead of e.getMessage().

Answer (score 0):

If its generating exception on this line:

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

It is because of null content in namevalue pairs OR default encoding issue. you may change it to the below line by adding utf-8 encoding

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "utf-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

its either a big mistake, or i am so dummy ...

you are passing file name as a key to the BasicNamevaluePair (http param)
and the value is empty string...

```
private String acc;
public void insert()
{
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(filepath,acc));
```

you have to read file content and pass them

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data",getFileContent(filepath));
```

at php page
you read 2 params not sent from the mobile app

```
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
```

at php page, read the param "data", save it to file **at server** and load its to db

```
$data=$_REQUEST['data'];
saveFile("myfile.txt", $data);
mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE myfile.txt INTO TABLE xfr") ",$con);
```